Best way to validate client form data
How can I ensure the validity of the client source for the application form we integrate into our client websites via a link?
Application form can be submitted without customer login on client websites.
For know we have assigned a unique ID to each client, which is hardcoded in the application form link that we provide to client. However, this ID is easily accessible through developer tools, potentially allowing spam users to submit multiple application form requests. How can we address this issue effectively?
